# Calculating how many additional increments there are

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: question]

So I have this mini assignment here and I figured out how to do every step except the very last one which is seeing how many additional 50g increments there are using only an If statement.

Here's what I've done so far for the rest:

```
// Parse textbox text to numbers and create variable
        double Weight = double.Parse(txtWeight.Text);

        // Classify weight categories
        if (Weight <= 30)
        {
            // change label text
            lblOutput.Text = "Your postage is $0.50";

        }
        else if((Weight > 30) && (Weight <= 50))
        {
            // change label text
            lblOutput.Text = "Your postage is $0.70";
        }
        else if ((Weight > 50) && (Weight <= 100))
        {
            // change label text
            lblOutput.Text = "Your postage is $0.90";
        }
        else if (Weight > 100)
        {
            // check how much poastage would be
            double heavyPostage = (Weight - 100) / 50 ;

            // change label text
            lblOutput.Text = "Your postage is 90 cents" + heavyPostage;
        };
```

Comment: round up and multiply by 0.18, e.g. `double heavyPostage = Math.Ceiling((Weight - 100) / 50) * 0.18` by the way how can it be $1.18 in the example? it could either be $1.08 or $1.26 ($0.9 for the 100g + $0.18 for extra 50g = $1.08, $0.9 for the 100g + $0.36 for extra 100g = $1.26)

Comment: @Steve,  I don't know what assumed about my previous comment but it's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to multiply the 50 grams increment obtained from Weight for 0.18, but there are also subtle problems to identify correctly.

First, given the input in grams I think you don't need to use a double but an integer will serve you better when making the division. You are not interested in the remainder of the division, but only to the integer part. So using an integer triggers the use of the integer division discarding the decimal part.

So let's make Weight an integer and add some safety check on the input

```
if(!Int32.TryParse(txtWeight.Text, out int Weight));
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not a number");
    return;
}
....
```

Now at the division point you should add 1 to the block of 50 grams counted if the remainder of the division is not zero

```
int heavyPostage = ((Weight - 100) / 50);
int remainder = (((Weight - 100) % 50) != 0 ? 1 : 0);
heavyPostage += remainder;
```

At this point the calculus is very simple

```
var result = 0.9 + (heavyPostage * .18);  
Console.WriteLine($"Your postage is $ {result}");
```

So for example with an input of 151grams you get "$ 1.26" while an input of 150grams will give you "$ 1.08"